Setting app config as a string variable instead of a config file
For my console app I have stored app.config in custom path for now
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", "c:\path to config file");
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");

I wonder how we can load app config XML from a String variable
//pseudo code
String configXML = "<my dynamic xml string>";
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", configXML);//<=looking for something like this


That doesn't make sense to me, really. Why would you hard code settings? The whole purpose of all that settings/configuration stuff is so to not have it hard coded ...

Why use app config then? You are adding extra efforts/overheads. Just go for your own file system instead of app config.

I would suggest reading documentation cf. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-8.0
